# SSRS 2008 R2 Report Manager Loads Slowly in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportmanager, ssrs-2008-r2

Within the last week or so, my SSRS Report Manager website performance has decreased drastically for three users. I'm not really sure why. Here are their stats

- User 1 is running a Virtual Machine with Windows XP and IE8.
- User 2 is running a Virtual Machine with Windows XP and IE8.
- User 3 is running a Virtual Machine with Windows 7 and IE9.

They are all seeing long loading times when navigating through the Report Manager website and running reports. I try to run the same reports with the same parameters as them and have no issues. I am running on a Laptop with Windows 7 and IE9. If I check ExecutionLog2 and compare their times vs my times, they are all in the same ball park so I don't think it is the server. As far as I know, nothing has changed on the Report Server recently that would have caused this. A few other things I tried.

- If User 1 runs FireFox, the Report Manager website runs fast.
- If User 1 runs the Report Manager Website from the Thin Client (laptop, non VM), using IE7, the site works fast
- I took a fourth user who does not regularly use the site. She has Windows 7 and IE8. It worked fine.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: My first thought was that SSRS2008R2 is able to make use of IE9's hardware rendering, but that wouldn't apply to your XP/IE8 boxes. There is a setting that probably should be off for boxes with poor video cards. 

When user 1 runs firefox, is that still in the XP Virtual machine? What VM software do you use? If they used to run fast and now don't, what has changed: updates to software, vm/OS/IE ?